# Microsoft Edge: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: null

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge

Automating tests to edge browser through webDriver using java script.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver",
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Web Driver\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

**Already install MicrosoftWebDriver**

**And using selenium webdriver 2.48.2**

**OS: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10565]**

But got and Exception:

Exception in thread "main"

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: null (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.14 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-DUHBOA4', ip: '192.168.31.26', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:152)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:98)
    at test.edge.browser.UseEdgeBrowser.main(UseEdgeBrowser.java:18)
```

No clue for this. Do I still need to configure something?

Comment: @MSEdgeDev I debug code, and found executing command **new session** does not get sessionId, so the **sessionID is null** .

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 kinds of 
1. Microsoft WebDriver: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48212

and

2. WebDriver for Windows Insiders: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48740

using 1 with this issue. using 2 works for me

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's some time ago, but here is the solution for everyone with the same error..

Your Windows build must be equal to the Microsoft WebDriver version(eg 14393). Just open start menu, type in "winver" and use the correct WebDriver (right hand side) on following page:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/